# onstartNestedScroll and onNestedPreScroll is deprecated in android studio. What is the alternative method?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

When I migrate my old android project from api-28 to api-30 onstartnestedscroll() method and onnestedprescroll() are deprecated in android api-30.So, Help me what is alternative method.

public class BottomNavigationBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior {

```
public BottomNavigationBehavior() {
    super();
}

public BottomNavigationBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, BottomNavigationView child, View dependency) {
    boolean dependsOn = dependency instanceof FrameLayout;
    return dependsOn;
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
}

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
    if (dy < 0) {
        showBottomNavigationView(child);
    } else if (dy > 0) {
        hideBottomNavigationView(child);
    }
}
```